# Android ListPreference with add-button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-preferences

Is there an example or maybe an already implemented ListPreference for Android, which has a TextView and a Button to add a new value to the list?

Something like this:

|------------------------| |Add|

- item
- item
- item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite simple to do.

1. Create a subclass of a ListPreference
2. Override the onPrepareDialogBuilder(Builder builder);
   2.1 Create a new adapter in which you use your custom layout (standard adapter)
   2.2 call builder.setAdapter()
3. Done!

see http://blog.isys-labs.com/creating-a-custom-listpreference/